# Time Complexity for a recurrence

Tags: functions, algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I have a recurrence of Divide and Conquer in which I can divide input $n$ into $f(n)$ parts and combining their solutions will take $O(f(n))$ time, where $f(n)$ is a function of $n$ and $f(n)\leq n$.

Formally the recurrence is: $T(n)=f(n)T(\frac{n}{f(n)})+O(f(n))$

What can be $T(n)$ in Big-oh notation (tight bound) and for which $f(n)$ ?

My guess is $T(n)=O(n^2)$.

Comment: I think you cannot find a general formula for this. I am guessing that $T(n)=O(n)$ for some nice family of functions $f(n)$. For instance, if $f(n)=n$, you have $T(n)=O(n)$ and if $f(n)=2$, you have $T(n)=O(n)$.